# Where do the borders come from in this WPF listview

Tags: wpf, listview, user-interface

I´m trying to make a listview look a certain way and i´ve managed to remove most of the UI elements that I don't want but I can't figure out where the border around selected items is coming from.

It's index 0 that is selected in the example. How do I remove that border?
[image: Example of problem]

Currently I´m the following code to remove the background and borderbrush.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Name="MainListView">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
```

The problem might be related to that when I mouse over the label I get a second grey row like so: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're using a Trigger to change the style, but you're not showing the *default* style.  If you want there to be no borders by default, just set that on the style directly.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `Template` for ListViewItem and rewrite it, excluding the elements and triggers that create the unwanted effects.  You can extract the default template in VS11's XAML Designer or in Blend, or you can find them in the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).  I personally prefer just rewriting them entirely because it allows me to refactor the oft-bloated XAML templates, rather than simply giving the illusion of simplicity by changing their default values to `{x:Null}`.  The less clutter in the visual tree, the better!